# How to change WP redirect on blog search?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am running a WP Blog.
In permalinks I set WP base URL to `https://www.url.com/blog`.
That is necessary and can't be changed.

If I try to use the WP-Search Widget for Blog it fails.
Because the URL WP is trying to redirect is wrong

> (..**/blog**/blog/?s=test).

Is there a way to say WP to use

> ../blog/?s=test

instead of

> ../blog/blog/?s=...

What I tried:
Put in functions.php this code (no success):

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
  if ( ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( site_url( "/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
  } 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

`.htaccess` can't be changed

Ideas are highly appreciated.

**Update to precise the question:**

When investigating the search with Chrome, it shows that WP redirect the request.

If I only could prevent WP vom redirecting!

Chrome console output:

Remote Address:10.236.1.21:443
Request URL:https://www.domain.com/blog/?s=schnuffi
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Response Headers
content-length:0
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Wed, 13 May 2015 08:52:46 GMT
location:https://www.domain.com/blog/blog/?s=schnuffi
server:nginx
status:302 Found
version:HTTP/1.1
....

Comment: so www.url.com/blog is your home page? why not point your home page to that blog page so that the url is www.url.com and then the permanent link need not have 2 "blogs" in it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the home page Url. **www.domain.com/blog** is fix.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't change the URL it is just a pointer, you can point it to wherever you like.  Have you tried posting on the Wordpress forum? There are some pretty helpful people there, maybe with more expertise specifically regarding wordpress.  Try here...https://wordpress.org/support/forum/how-to-and-troubleshooting

Comment: It is because of two server serving a website. One server is delivering normally (provider). The other is (home) looking for "www.domain.de/blog" to serve the blog-part. However, it is probably a more hardcore WP thing to dig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the following function (I learnt you have implemented in your code):

```
function change_blog_url() {
if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET's' ) )
    { wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) ); exit(); }
}
```

Wordpress should stop adding an additional "/blog" and the URL is resolved properly.

Comment: Pille a colleague of mine discovered the issue in functions.php . Now the blog-search works. Great work, Pille.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `is_search()` function into your condition. This function checks if search result page archive is being displayed. --> more at [**Wordpress codex**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_search) page

And then try to add the `exit()` function into the end of your function.

So your function may looks like:

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
  if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( site_url( "/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) ); exit();
  } 
}
```

Comment: :-) That's exactly what I mentioned in the question. Did not work. I need a way to say WP: "Don't add another /blog on my home Url (=www.domain.com/blog)"

Comment: You can try to use `home_url()` instead of `site_url()`

Answer (score 0):

In theme directory create file **searchform.php** and put 
this code in it:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Change the form action attribute whatever you want, by default it will always print home url which will be your site url. eg: http://example.com/ so when your form get submitted it will make request to http://example.com?s=query.

Comment: If your current site url is : http://example.com/blog then the function home_url() will automatically return http://example.com/blog, or else you can use site_url();